# Why is lucene single char wildcard query finding less docs than when fully specifying wildcard?

Tags: java, lucene

I have an index that contains the values `abc` and `def` in the analyzers default field and belong to two different documents. When I execute the query `abc OR def` then I get hits for both of the documents in the index. But when I use `abc OR d?f` I only get a hit for the document containing `abc`. When I query the index with `d?f` I get a hit for the document containing `def`.

When I have a look at the parsed query for `abc OR d?f` I see a correct result. That means that a `BooleanQuery` is parsed that has a `WildcardQuery` as a second clause.

Am I doing something wrong?

In my application I also have another boolean clause on top of the one specified above. This matches a different field than that was specified above. So a complete query in my case would be: `user:john AND (abc OR d?f)`. But all documents in my index contain `john` in the `user` field. So that should not be the problem.

I'm using lucene 3.0.3.

**EDIT:**
I had a look at the index using [luke](http://www.getopt.org/luke/). There I saw that in the rewritten query the term `d?f` was replaced by `()`. Knowing that it is obvious that the query will only match `abc`. But why is the wildcard term replaced when rewriting the query?

Comment: I must admit I'm not familiar with Lucene, but a cursory look at the documentation seems to confirm that your use should be correct. My initial thought would be that something is causing your second query to be interpreted as a regex as that would cause it to not find `def`, but as I said, I don't know enough about Lucene to know. It's just a thought that I figured might be useful to you.

Comment: From your description it all looks correct. I guess the only way to solve this is to extract your use case into a separate self-contained runnable class which demonstrates this problem.

Comment: @maxbeaudoin I'm currently working on a sscce.

Comment: @SpaceTrucker damn I had to google that haha!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was just my fault. The data that was used in the test scenario was a bit more complex. So the term `abc` was appearing multiple times in the index. But I only fetched the 10 top scored docs from the index. Since the query matched `abc` before `d?f` with the top score those results were first. And hence the docs containing `def` weren't found by the query.